# How to display a photo to Organization Chart?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, development

I have a list like following [image]

and I have an organization chart based on this list:[image]

I need above the name to be displayed an Image from `Publishing Image` and it is also `Publishing Image` column type  how can I display It.

Here is my code: I am using google charts and i need image to be with 100x60px

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Fields;

namespace OrganizationChartUsingGoogleAPI.OrganizationChart
{
public static class ConvertTo
{
/// <summary>
/// Convert the object type in the given type and handle the DBNULL.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Type to convert</typeparam>
/// <param name="value">value</param>
/// <returns>converted value and if DBNULL then return the type's default value i.e. string = string.Empty, Int16=0 </returns>
public static T CastIn<T>(this object value) where T : IConvertible
{
    if (value == DBNull.Value)
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
        {
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(string.Empty, typeof(T));
        }
        else
        {
            return default(T);
        }


    if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool))
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(Convert.ToInt32(value), typeof(T));

    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
}
}

public partial class OrganizationChartUserControl : UserControl
{
//Get the List name to fetch the data from
string listName = "OrgChart_Demo";
int iRowCounter = 0;
string sAllNewRows = string.Empty;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Fetch the data (recursively) from the list
    GetNode(string.Empty);

    //Generate the Client Script and Register
    GenerateClientScript(sAllNewRows);
}

private void GenerateClientScript(string sAllNewRows)
{
    string csName1 = "OrgChartScript";
    Type csType = this.GetType();

    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

    // Check to see if the startup script is already registered. 
    if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(csType, csName1))
    {
        StringBuilder cstext = new StringBuilder();
        cstext.Append("<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>");
        cstext.Append("<script type='text/javascript'>");
        cstext.Append("google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['orgchart'] });");
        cstext.Append("google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);");

        cstext.Append("function drawChart() {");
        cstext.Append("var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();");

        cstext.Append("data.addColumn('string', 'Name');");
        //cstext.Append("data.addColumn('string', 'Picture');");
        cstext.Append("data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');");
        cstext.Append("data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');");
        cstext.Append("var rowArr = new Array();");

        cstext.Append(sAllNewRows);

        cstext.Append("data.addRows(rowArr);");

        cstext.Append("var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));");
        cstext.Append("chart.draw(data, { allowHtml: true, allowCollapse: true });");
        cstext.Append("}");
        cstext.Append("</script>");
        cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(csType, csName1, cstext.ToString(), false);

    }

}

private void GetNode(string reportsTo)
{
    SPListItemCollection itemCol = GetListItems(listName, reportsTo);

    foreach (SPListItem item in itemCol)
    {
        //create a new row
        sAllNewRows += createNewRow(item);

        //Recursion
        GetNode(item["Name"].ToString());
    }

}

private string createNewRow(SPListItem listItem)
{
    string sName = ConvertTo.CastIn<string>(listItem["Name"]);
    string sTitle = ConvertTo.CastIn<string>(listItem["Title"]);
    string sMoreInfo = ConvertTo.CastIn<string>(listItem["MoreInfo"]);
    string sReportsTo = ConvertTo.CastIn<string>(listItem["ReportsTo"]);

    //ImageFieldValue pageImage = listItem["Pageimage"] as ImageFieldValue;
    //string sPicture = string.IsNullOrEmpty(pageImage.ImageUrl) ? "#" : pageImage.ImageUrl;

   // string sReportsTo = new SPFieldLookupValue(ConvertTo.CastIn<string>(listItem["ReportsTo"])).LookupValue;



    StringBuilder sText = new StringBuilder();
    sText.Append("var NewRow = new Array();");
    sText.Append(String.Format("NewRow.push({{ v: '{0}', f: '{1}<div style=\"color:red; font-style:italic\">{2}</div>' }});", sName, sName, sTitle));
   // sText.Append(String.Format("NewRow.push({{ v: '{0}', '<img src='{1}'/>', f: '{2}<div style=\"color:red; font-style:italic\">{3}</div>' }});",sName,sPicture, sName, sTitle));

    sText.Append(String.Format("NewRow.push('{0}');", sReportsTo));
    sText.Append(String.Format("NewRow.push('{0}');", sMoreInfo));
    sText.Append(String.Format("rowArr[{0}] = NewRow;", iRowCounter));

  // Pageimage

    iRowCounter++;
    return sText.ToString();
}

private SPListItemCollection GetListItems(string destList, string reportsTo)
{
    SPListItemCollection ResultListItems = null;

    using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
    {
        using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
        {
            SPList list = oWeb.Lists.TryGetList(destList);
            if (null == list)
                return ResultListItems;

            //Check if the item already exist.
            StringBuilder sCAMLQuery = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
            sCAMLQuery.Append("<Where>");
            if (reportsTo != string.Empty)
            {
                sCAMLQuery.Append("<Eq>");
                sCAMLQuery.Append("<FieldRef Name='ReportsTo' />");
              //  sCAMLQuery.Append("<Value Type='Lookup'>" + reportsTo + "</Value>");
                sCAMLQuery.Append("<Value Type='Text'>" + reportsTo + "</Value>");

                sCAMLQuery.Append("</Eq>");
            }
            else
            {
                sCAMLQuery.Append("<IsNull>");
                sCAMLQuery.Append("<FieldRef Name='ReportsTo' />");
                sCAMLQuery.Append("</IsNull>");
            }
            sCAMLQuery.Append("</Where>");

            SPQuery QueryResult = new SPQuery();
            QueryResult.Query = sCAMLQuery.ToString();
            ResultListItems = list.GetItems(QueryResult);
        }
    }

    return ResultListItems;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to upload the picture in SharePoint list? Or do you want to get the Picture from SharePoint list in below given code? as both are missing.

Comment: Kindly check this for your reference...http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Create-Organizational-Chart-from-Database-using-Google-Organizational-Chart-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: @Hardik I have the photo in list but for some reason it is not displayed in above picture. I have i ton my list all I want is to display it to the chart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `CreateNewRow` function with below code.

```
public partial class OrganizationChartUserControl : UserControl
{
    //Get the List name to fetch the data from
    string listName = "OrgChart_Demo";
    int iRowCounter = 0;
    string sAllNewRows = string.Empty;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Fetch the data (recursively) from the list
        GetNode(string.Empty);

        //Generate the Client Script and Register
        GenerateClientScript(sAllNewRows);
    }

    private void GenerateClientScript(string sAllNewRows)
    {
        string csName1 = "OrgChartScript";
        Type csType = this.GetType();

        ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

        // Check to see if the startup script is already registered. 
        if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(csType, csName1))
        {
            StringBuilder cstext = new StringBuilder();
            cstext.Append("<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>");
            cstext.Append("<script type='text/javascript'>");
            cstext.Append("google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['orgchart'] });");
            cstext.Append("google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);");

            cstext.Append("function drawChart() {");
            cstext.Append("var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();");

            cstext.Append("data.addColumn('string', 'Picture');");
            cstext.Append("data.addColumn('string', 'Name');");
            cstext.Append("data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');");
            cstext.Append("data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');");
            cstext.Append("var rowArr = new Array();");

            cstext.Append(sAllNewRows);

            cstext.Append("data.addRows(rowArr);");

            cstext.Append("var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));");
            cstext.Append("chart.draw(data, { allowHtml: true, allowCollapse: true });");
            cstext.Append("}");
            cstext.Append("</script>");
            cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(csType, csName1, cstext.ToString(), false);

        }

    }

    private void GetNode(string reportsTo)
    {
        SPListItemCollection itemCol = GetListItems(listName, reportsTo);

        foreach (SPListItem item in itemCol)
        {
            //create a new row
            sAllNewRows += createNewRow(item);

            //Recursion
            GetNode(item["Name"].ToString());
        }

    }

    private string createNewRow(SPListItem listItem)
    {
        string sName = ConvertTo.CastIn<string>(listItem["Name"]);
        string sTitle = ConvertTo.CastIn<string>(listItem["Title"]);
        string sMoreInfo = ConvertTo.CastIn<string>(listItem["MoreInfo"]);
        string sReportsTo = ConvertTo.CastIn<string>(listItem["ReportsTo"]);


        ImageFieldValue pageImage = listItem["Publishing Image"] as ImageFieldValue;
        string sPicture = string.IsNullOrEmpty(pageImage.ImageUrl) ? "#" : pageImage.ImageUrl;

       // string sReportsTo = new SPFieldLookupValue(ConvertTo.CastIn<string>(listItem["ReportsTo"])).LookupValue;

        StringBuilder sText = new StringBuilder();
        sText.Append("var NewRow = new Array();");

        sText.Append(String.Format("NewRow.push({{ v: '{0}', f: '<img src = "{1}" />{2}<div style=\"color:red; font-style:italic\">{3}</div>' }});", sName, sPicture, sName, sTitle));

        sText.Append(String.Format("NewRow.push('{0}');", sReportsTo));
        sText.Append(String.Format("NewRow.push('{0}');", sMoreInfo));
        sText.Append(String.Format("rowArr[{0}] = NewRow;", iRowCounter));

        iRowCounter++;
        return sText.ToString();
    }

    private SPListItemCollection GetListItems(string destList, string reportsTo)
    {
        SPListItemCollection ResultListItems = null;

        using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
        {
            using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList list = oWeb.Lists.TryGetList(destList);
                if (null == list)
                    return ResultListItems;

                //Check if the item already exist.
                StringBuilder sCAMLQuery = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
                sCAMLQuery.Append("<Where>");
                if (reportsTo != string.Empty)
                {
                    sCAMLQuery.Append("<Eq>");
                    sCAMLQuery.Append("<FieldRef Name='ReportsTo' />");
                  //  sCAMLQuery.Append("<Value Type='Lookup'>" + reportsTo + "</Value>");
                    sCAMLQuery.Append("<Value Type='Text'>" + reportsTo + "</Value>");

                    sCAMLQuery.Append("</Eq>");
                }
                else
                {
                    sCAMLQuery.Append("<IsNull>");
                    sCAMLQuery.Append("<FieldRef Name='ReportsTo' />");
                    sCAMLQuery.Append("</IsNull>");
                }
                sCAMLQuery.Append("</Where>");

                SPQuery QueryResult = new SPQuery();
                QueryResult.Query = sCAMLQuery.ToString();
                ResultListItems = list.GetItems(QueryResult);
            }
        }

        return ResultListItems;
    }
}
```

I have added `sPicture` in the function to get the Picture URL from SharePoint list item's "**Publishing Image**" column & show that in `NewRow` data using below line.

```
sText.Append(String.Format("NewRow.push({{ v: '><img src = "{0}" />', f: '{1}<div style=\"color:red; font-style:italic\">{2}</div>' }});", sPicture, sName, sTitle));
```

Please try above code & let me know as I haven't created same functionality on my-end but just changed the above code from taking the reference from below link.

[Create Organizational Chart from Database using Google Organizational Chart in ASP.Net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Create-Organizational-Chart-from-Database-using-Google-Organizational-Chart-in-ASPNet.aspx)

Comment: I think this is the correct you wanted to write `sText.Append(String.Format("NewRow.push({{ v: '<img src = '{0}' />', f: '{1}<div style=\"color:red; font-style:italic\">{2}</div>' }});", sPicture, sName, sTitle));` am I right

Comment: yes as this will show you an image above the name in chart

Comment: I am getting a `System.NullReferenceException`

Comment: Have you added these two lines in your code?....** ImageFieldValue pageImage = listItem["Publishing Image"] as ImageFieldValue;
        string sPicture = string.IsNullOrEmpty(pageImage.ImageUrl) ? "#" : pageImage.ImageUrl; **

Comment: yes I have added them

Comment: Previously there was **item["Publishing Image"] as ImageFieldValue;** so i changed it to **listItem["Publishing Image"] as ImageFieldValue;**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41410/discussion-between-hardik-and-nderon-hyseni).

Comment: I think that mistakes stays here `sText.Append(String.Format("NewRow.push({{ v: '<img src = '{0}' />', f: '{1}<div style=\"color:red; font-style:italic\">{2}</div>' }});", sPicture, sName, sTitle));` please can you check it. thanks for your support I really appreciate it

Comment: I have Updated your answer with my full code check it

Comment: I don't know how to thank you, you are a life saver thank you so much If i Could i will give you 150 reputation to show my appreciate. Thanks